# add authentication to teams bot for specific users using azure and bot framework

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

is there a way to make my bot is accessible only by specific users from different organizations ?
I know about Identity provider but it's good for services that need auth on behalf of the user like email service in Graph API but i use Qna Maker and it doesn't have on behalf of the user permission.

Comment: If you already have authentication set up, you can use the access-tokens' claims to identify the requesting user and his tenant and thus restrict or allow access only for specific users.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users

Answer (score 0):

This question will be tracked from [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/microsoft-teams-authentication/m-p/2262729#M2967).